# Can I use "import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;" with Facebook SDK 3.23.1?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

In my app\build.gradle file, I have `compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'`. In my BaseActivity.java file (where I have "public class BaseActivity extends Activity"), I am trying to use this: `import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;`. This is the error I get:

```
Error:(8, 20) error: cannot find symbol class FacebookSdk
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

I am using https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/ to follow the instructions for adding Facebook SDK to a project. One of the steps is: "Import Facebook SDK into your app", and they provide the following line:

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
```

Is it possible to do this with Facebook SDK 3.23.1? I wonder if the instructions imply the use of Facebook SDK 4.0.0 or higher.

UPDATE: I am copying my dependencies below.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile files('libs/AndroidSDK-2.15.9.jar')
compile files('libs/core.jar')
compile files('libs/easyfacebookandroidsdk_2.3.jar')
compile files('libs/PayPal_MPL.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
compile files('libs/socialauth-4.2.jar')
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
compile files('libs/urbanairship-lib-3.3.0.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'}
```

Comment: In a few words, can I use Facebook Analytics with Facebook SDK v3.x, or do I need Facebook SDK v4.x?

Comment: Why would you want v3.x ?

Comment: Because my App was created a while ago and it uses v3.x.

Comment: Ok, no problem, you can compile the latest version as described in my answer and your error will be fixed hopefully.

Comment: It was not fixed, but it created new errors because I was using functions that required Facebook SDK v3.x. I followed the instructions at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23.1/class/AppEventsLogger/ and using the AppEventsLogger class as explained in that link was the solution. Finally Facebook Analytics works for me with Facebook SDK v3.23.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, “import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;” is only available from Facebook SDK 4.0.0. Yes, it is possible to use Facebook Analytics with Facebook SDK v3.x. I finally have Facebook Analytics working using Facebook SDK v3.23.1. I used the AppEventsLogger class as explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.23.1/class/AppEventsLogger/.

Answer (score 1):

Use the latest version of facebook SDK. I've integrated it recently and it's working fine.

```
dependencies{

compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'

}
```

Comment: Using SDK v4.+ generates many new errors in my App. So I was trying to continue using SDK v3.x., unless it is absolutely required to upgrade. I was trying to confirm if SDK v3.x supports Facebook Analytics. I have not found that information in Facebook Developer's official documentation. Otherwise, I may just need to upgrade and fix the many new errors I see when trying to use SDK 4.+.

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile files('libs/AndroidSDK-2.15.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/easyfacebookandroidsdk_2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/PayPal_MPL.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/socialauth-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:3.23.1'
}

Comment: Facebook sdk v3.x.x does not contain com.facebook.Facebook package. If you want to follow the latest method, you have to use v4.x.x. Otherwise if you don't want to change version, you can follow the old method which may suit to your need - http://code2care.org/pages/integrating-android-facebook-sdk-v3.17.2-tutorial/ . Since v3's last version is almost 2 years old, it is recommended to use prior v3 (4.0.0 or 4.+)

Comment: I already have Facebook SDK v3.x up and running on my App, and that is what I am using to implement the Facebook Login button. The only problem is that when I try to integrate Facebook Analytics, I need to use "import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;", which is not available in Facebook SDK v3.x. I guess Facebook SDK v3.x does not support Facebook Analytics, and my only option would be to upgrade from Facebook SDK v3.x to v4.x, which is a major version upgrade.

Comment: In the official instructions from https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/ to add Facebook SDK, they say: "Add compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)' to your build.gradle dependencies." I am not sure what "[4,5)" means. I guess it means v4.x. I was trying to find a confirmation that Facebook SDK v3.x does not support Facebook Analytics, but I guess that seems to be the case.

Comment: I was reading the Facebook Analytics for Apps FAQ at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/analytics/faq and they say in the Troubleshooting section: "If you're using version 3.19.0 or earlier of the Facebook SDK for Android, there's an issue with counting all app installs." That makes me believe that it is possible to implement Facebook Analytics with Facebook SDK 3.x.

Comment: I am finally using Facebook Analytics with Facebook SDK 3.23.1. It works.