# include facebook sdk in android studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm followed some tuts for including the FB SDK 
but when I want to import

```
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
```

I need this for FB analytics, so I'm created the class fbanalytic :

[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtPYS.png)

and we see it's hidden i dont know fix it

and also someone his tell that class it's not important specialy in the latest version in fb sdk ,is that correct?
currently im using  latest verion :facebook-android-sdk-4.22.1

Comment: You are not using the FacebookSdk on your code, thats why is grey

Comment: ok,in first step im creating new project to import fb-sdk ,
but the second when i want to use  import fb-sdk in existing project his hidden 
do you know how fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Facebook SDK:

1. Import the sdk by adding compile dependency to `build.gradle` file

   dependencies { 
     compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
   }
2. Now when you are trying to use something from Facebook's SDK it should be AUTOMATICALLY imported to your files.

In your example you are making a new Class that does uses `AppEventsLogger` that is part of Facebook SDK. The import statement that you presumably wrote (`import com.facebook.FacebookSDK`) is grey and second import statement clearly shows that it is importing form `com.facebook.*` SDK.

tldr: Android Studio imports from Facebook SDK as expected.

Comment: ok thanks, very helpfull explain method
jsut now i make sure that classes are import automatically
i'm leave this class analytic and i checked the admin developer FB
and the analytic work fine 
tnx

Answer (score 0):

Add  in build.gladle within dependencies bracket:

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'`

Might be [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493510/can-i-use-import-com-facebook-facebooksdk-with-facebook-sdk-3-23-1).