# Can't import com.facebook packages to MainApplication.java

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I am upgrading to RN 0.60.5 and and my imports of com.facebook packages in MainApplication.java (import com.facebook.***) can't be found.

Getting errors such : " error: cannot find symbol import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;"

Tried to change the version of RN in the import of the package in build.gradle

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
```

to :

```
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.60.5"
```

and it did not worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42493510/can-i-use-import-com-facebook-facebooksdk-with-facebook-sdk-3-23-1

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by adding

`implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'`